# Set multiple models in render function, with the possibility to observe, reboot and save each separately

Tags: ember.js

i have a problem with Ember.RSVP.hash(). Models does not render in templates, observes not work with promise model, and promise does not function reload().

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({     
  achievementMode: true,
  params:[],
  model(params){
    this.set('params', params);
    return params;
  },
  renderTemplate(controller, model){
    var firstController = this.controllerFor('clients/'+model.first),
        secondController = this.controllerFor('clients/'+model.second),
        firstModel = this.getModel(model.first,model),
        secondModel = this.getModel(model.second,model);

    this.render('clients/'+model.first,{
      outlet:'first',
      controller:firstController,
      model: Ember.RSVP.hash(firstModel)
    });
    this.render('clients/'+model.second,{
      outlet:'second',
      controller:secondController,
      model: Ember.RSVP.hash(secondModel)
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('clients').set('firstBlock', model.first);
    this.controllerFor('clients').set('secondBlock', model.second);
  },
  getModel(modelName, params){
    var model = {};
    if(modelName === 'profile'){
      model ['client'] = this.store.findRecord('user', params.user_id, { reload: true }),
      model ['achievements'] = this.store.query('achievement', {'mode':this.get('achievementMode'),'user':params.user_id})
    }
    model ['params'] = params;
    return model;
  }
});
```

Have a rest adapter, and after request observes('params') not work, and params not render in template.

```
{{#each achievements as |achievement|}}
test
{{/each}}
```

and promise not have a function reload().
ember 2.2
any thoughts? how to implement plans?

Comment: i do not even know where to begin with this... your model hook should just return an `RSVP.hash`... which is your `findRecord` and your `query`... forget all of the renderTemplate and just use components to render each block of content... if i have time i will try to write up a better answer for you

Comment: You are really fighting against the grain of the framework here. Do you have a sketch of the UI you want to build?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. this [link](https://yadi.sk/i/oqigk_WcpXD2B) UI. Problem is in two dynamic blocks. In each of them will render any of four variants. And i choose URL model: /clients/Number_User/first_block/second_block Router `this.route('clients', function() {
      this.route('edit', {path: '/:user_id/:first/:second'});
  });`

Comment: Use components for this! *Don't* override `renderTemplate`! Easiest thing is to just build two components, and give them the `first` and `second`. Then do the fun in the component. Don't use `first` and `second` as dynamic segments but use query params. Thats how you can have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i don't understand, how i render multiple any models if will use the component for this?